# Sales order Edit in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I have add item option dropdown in my sales order edit now i want to save this value on my product option where i can make changes

Comment: u can enable path hints for admin section

Answer (score 1):

This will show the template hints for admin panel

```
Run the following query on the Magento database:

INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value)

VALUES ('websites', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),

('websites', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

you will able to hint of template and also block

Answer (score 1):

you can also use in `config.xml` file put these lines

```
<config>
...
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>
...
</config>
```